# Standardizing time between entries for time series data in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, unnest

So I have this BigQuery Code for working with the MIMIC database

So I have this table in BigQuery that has a bunch of time-series information for individuals but at varying times, so some may have it every 5 minutes and others are every 5 hours and some are scattered.

I want to build a version of the table where every individual will have one entry every 4 hours and nothing more, i.e. entries within each 4 hour interval would be averaged.

This is what I have right now

```
WITH minmax as(
SELECT subject_id, hadm_id, icustay_id , min(charttime) as mint, max(charttime) as maxt
FROM `projectx-mcgill.preprocessing.overalltable_Lab_withventparams`
GROUP BY icustay_id, subject_id, hadm_id
ORDER BY icustay_id, subject_id, hadm_id
    ), grid as (
    SELECT icustay_id, subject_id, hadm_id, 
    
    UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(CAST(mint as timestamp), CAST(maxt as timestamp), INTERVAL 4 HOUR)) as start_time

    FROM minmax
    GROUP BY icustay_id, subject_id, hadm_id,mint,maxt
    ORDER BY icustay_id, subject_id, hadm_id)
```

and I'm trying to get start_time to be similar to postgres' generate_sequence() function so I can get a row with each persons info at progressive 4 hour marks but I keep getting "Syntax error: Expected "(" but got keyword UNNEST". I found somewhere saying that UNNEST can't be before the FROM clause but when I move it behind I get a new error saying that the table is not grouped or aggregated. Any idea of what I could do?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/507852

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Create a timestamps table:

```
    WITH timestamps AS
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM   UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2021-01-01 00:00:00', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                                INTERVAL 4 HOUR)) AS ts
        )
    SELECT * FROM timestamps AS t
```

2. Get the distinct entites from your data:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT subject_id, hadm_id, icustay_id FROM <your_table>
```

3. `CROSS JOIN` the previous two relations such that every "entity" has an row for every timestamp
4. Finally, `LEFT/RIGHT` join the relation from the previous step with an aggregation of your data, joining on timestamp (rounded or otherwise somehow truncated to 4 hour intervals), aggregating as needed and using something like `IFNULL()` or `COALESCE()` to handle those timestamps containing no data for an entity.

Note: the MIMIC database/`projectx-mcgill` doesn't appear to be a public dataset, but if you're able to provide some small sample of your data, I can provide a more concrete example of this method.